# XCODE No such module 'TesseractOCR'

Tags: ios, cocoapods, tesseract

import TesseractOCR

This is the error I get :

> No such module 'TesseractOCR'

Please view attached image

[image: Project View[![][1]]
[image: Project View[![][2]]

Comment: Can you show your pod file ?

Comment: @MdRashedPervez : How is this link similar to this problem ?

Comment: My Podfile.  platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'JustCall' do
 pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', '4.0.0'
end

Comment: I don't understand your question? I linked 2 images from my Xcode project that show (to the best of my understanding ) that I installed the desired pod.   Thanks, David

Comment: Just to confirm, open Pods-JustCall folder and check that framework files are there.

Comment: Did you restart Xcode after pod install and build the project ?

Comment: Yes. I did open myproject.xcworkspace

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Clean the project
2. Delete tesseractOCR framework from ^this place
3. Delete Derived Data
4. Go to your project -> delete pods folder (not the pod file)
5. Re install the pods

Now it will work.

Comment: What do you  mean - clean the project- ? . Should I delete it from 'Linked FrameWork and Libraries'?  Thanks, David

Comment: What is - Derived Data -(?). There are 2 Pods folders on the project (image 2 ) . Thanks, David

Comment: Press Shift + Command + K to clean the project. 
Xcode -> Preferences -> Location -> Derived Data -> Delete Folder
..... Open the project in Finder and then delete the pods folder there will be one just delete it then run pod install in terminal again